# SQL server with row level security and entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a database (MS SQL Server) where row level security is used for the tables. Will there be any complications if I want to use that with Entity Framework. For example assume I have a n:n relation between students and courses like this:

```
Student:
Bob
Alice

Course:
Math
History

Student_Course:
Bob | Math
Bob | History
Alice | Math
Alice | History
```

"Course" table has row level access and I am not allowed to see the row "History". So what will happen if I have fetched Bob from the "Student" table and then do something like:

```
var bobsCourses = bobTheStudent.Courses
```

- The framework is smart enough to give me [Math]?
- I get [Math, null]?
- Everything will crash and burn because the entry in "Student_Course" does not have a match in "Course"?

The database already exists but not the application so this is "database first"
The application will only be used for data presenting, so no need to care about writing any updates to the database.

Comment: Not sure why "Math" becomes red, please ignore that.

Comment: This is something that's easily verifiable through your own testing.   Get on it!

Answer (score 0):

It would *probably* break unless you applied the RLS predicate to the Student_Course table as well.  RLS doesn't "cascade" in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing, it seems to be working like this:
For n:n relations there is no problem, the example works fine and the result will be [Math].
It's a little bit more complicated for 1:1 relations, e.g. assume we have these tables:

```
Student:         ### Table with students + main subject foreign key
Bob | Math
Alice | History

Subject:   ### Subjects
Math       ### This row is private
History
```

Then:

```
AllStudents
```

will give me [Bob, Alice]
and

```
BobTheStudent.MainSubject
```

will simply be null.
But then comes the scary stuff...

```
AllStudents.Include("MainSubject")
```

will give me [Alice].
I guess that's because in that case an SQL inner join will be used to retrieve the data from both tables. (Probably it will be different if null values were allowed for the foreign key, but I did not test that.)